# How can I redirect a static url to a dynamic one via HTACCESS?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I redirect `www.domain.com/sitedomain` to `www.domain.com/dir/directory/sitedomain.htm` through htaccess?

Example is:

```
www.domain.com/google.com -> www.domain.com/dir/directory/google.com.htm
```

Any easy way to  do this?

Comment: Cleaned up formatting

Comment: @anubhava yes actually..but got it solved already thanks to hjpotter92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the following rules a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+\.(com|net|info|io|in|cz|org))$ /dir/directory/$1.htm [L,QSA]
```

You can replace `[L` with `[L,R` if you want to redirect users as well. You can add more subdomains to the list above by editing the part `(com|net|info|io|in|cz|org)`.